# Use loop to print an array

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

Im building a program in which you can enter the tasks you have to do per day.
Now I'm trying to make the program print a list of all the tasks when you're done adding them.
This is the code I have:

```
for x in range(0,len(tuesday)):
     print(" -",x)
```

`tuesday` is an array that contains all the tasks for that day. However, this code doesn't work; it just prints some numbers. How can I make the `for` loop print all the tasks from the `tuesday` array?

Comment: How do you initialize the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for x in range(0,len(tuesday)):
     print(" -",x)
```

This code is not printing "random" numbers per se. It is printing the indices of all the elements in the tuesday array.

If you want to print the elements themselves, you will have to use this code:

```
for x in range(0,len(tuesday)):
 print(" -",tuesday[x])
```

or

```
for x in tuesday:
 print (x)
```

Comment: Thx! This is useful. Is probably better to use the second option but it won't harm me knowing how to do it another way.

Comment: Yet another option would be "for i, value in enumerate(tuesday):".

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
tuesday = ["feed the dog", "do the homework", "go to sleep"]

for x in tuesday:
    print x
```

would print:

```
feed the dog
do the homework
go to sleep
```

Comment: Or if you specifically need to use the index for whatever reason, `for x in range(0, len(tuesday)): print tuesday[x]`

Comment: @tripleee: if we need the index, we should probably write `for i,x in enumerate(tuesday):`.

Comment: if you "need the index" ther is a better approach = `enumerate()`